# minimum number of points to achieve "good" fit to exponential function

Tags: sample-size, curve-fitting

I am building a scientific instrument that measures exponentially decaying signals.  We sample points from the exponential decay (A*exp(-kt)+c), and then fit them to determine k, the time constants.  The instrument generates thousands of these curves a second, so it is important to be as efficient as possible.  Currently we sample 100s or 1000s of points per curve.  This is probably way more than we need to sample, but we currently don't know how many we need to sample.

The question for you is: How many points should we sample to achieve a given level of accuracy?

This will clearly depend on the noisiness of the data.  Given some normally distributed amount of noise, I'd like to be able to say, for example, if we want values on our curve fit to be within 5% of the true value, we will need to sample at least 30 points.  I'd like to know how the number of points required varies depending on the amount of noise.

We could set up a Monte Carlo model and come up with an answer, but it seems like someone must have already found a simpler solution.  I just don't know it!

Comment: Is your noise really constant as the mean changes? Or is it more like a relative error?

Comment: I'm not sure which mean you're asking about.  The noise is certainly not constant.  I would expect it to be normally distributed and quantifiable as some standard deviation about the true exponential decay.

Comment: 1. By "the mean" I intend the conditional mean under the model: $E(Y|T=t) = A\exp(-kt)+c$. When you wrote $A\exp(-kt)+c$ you cannot literally have meant that your observed values were equal to that (or 3 observations would be sufficient to obtain the parameters $A,k$ and $c$).]  If you observe the value $Y$ with noise your model for $Y$ has noise in some form.  2. If the noise isn't constant, how are you fitting the model? Just by unweighted nonlinear least squares? (treating deviations from the differently precise observations as equally important)

Comment: I see.  Yes, the data are noisy, so they clearly cannot follow Aexp(−kt)+c exactly.  Yes, NLS is what I would use.  I haven't actually built a model yet.

Comment: An answer will depend on the level of noise, the arrangement of $t$ values and the particular parameters, and (where the noise varies) the way in which that happens. I'd suggest not ignoring the heteroskedasticity.